# How do you get rid of malicious safari browser extension?

Tags: macos, browser, safari, osx-yosemite, safari-extensions

I am running Safari 8.0.4 on OS X 10.10.2

I think when I installed filezilla there was also a malicious browser extension installed in Safari. Here is what the extension preferences panel looks like:
[image: safari browser extension]

This extension seems to make everything go to yahoo. My home page and search engine is now changed to Yahoo. I can't get it back to what it was before. I also can't install any other browser extensions in Safari. Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Safari Extensions are in:

per-user:
`~/Library/Safari/Extensions`

General "Netscape API" browser plug-ins are in:

per user:
`~/Library/Internet\ Plug-ins/`

and

system-wide:
`/Library/Internet\ Plug-ins/`

Honestly, the problem with localized strings not found seems like corruption or a missing file within the Safari.app bundle. Like maybe a missing or corrupt copy of this file:

`/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/localizedStrings.js`